# Change modal size using Yii 1

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

The modal that I want to create need to set the size to be large but when I add the tag
    `'size'=>'large'`
on the button that generates the modal, it makes the button large and the modal stays at the same size. Also Tried to add the same tag inside the modal like this:

```
`<?php $this->beginWidget(
'booster.widgets.TbModal',
array(['id' => 'availability-modal',
'size'=>'large'])
);?>`
```

It returns
Property "TbModal.0" is not defined.

Is there another way to change the modal size?

Comment: I think this error is because you have an array inside an array `array(['id' => 'availability-modal',
'size'=>'large'])` it should be just `array('id' => 'availability-modal')`
And I think you can change modal size with css.

Comment: Tried to add the class _modal-lg_ but does nothing
`array('id' => 'availability-modal',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'modal-dialog modal-lg',
        ),)`

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: Its the version v3.3.4